# Please help - Cannot update packages Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates

I have tried:

sudo apt-get update

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://software.virtualmin.com/vm/6/gpl/apt virtualmin-xenial InRelease
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:5 http://software.virtualmin.com/vm/6/gpl/apt virtualmin-universal InRelease
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Fetched 323 kB in 1s (283 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
```

sudo apt-get upgrade

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-122-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  distro-info-data grub-legacy-ec2 linux-libc-dev wget
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 877 kB/1,177 kB of archives.
After this operation, 598 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

sudo apt-get -f install

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-122-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 598 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-124 linux-headers-4.4.0-124-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-122-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  distro-info-data grub-legacy-ec2 linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev wget
5 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 187 MB/187 MB of archives.
After this operation, 146 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

It doesn't let me choose Y/n, it aborts by it self...

I don't have much experience in Ubuntu. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your problem.  It looks like you upgraded the `upgrade` & `--fix-broken` yourself, and I see no errors listed in your update of repo.lists.

Comment: Virtualmin alerts me that I have 5 packages to update: 1)distro-info-data, 2) grub-legacy-ec2, 3) linux-headers-generic, 4)linux-libc-dev and 5)wget. However, when I click to update the selected packages it doesn't (it keeps on the same page, no action, and I have to go back). I want to update all packages.

Comment: I know nothing about `virtualmin`; but I see only evidence of using `upgrade` which has various rules that restrict what it can upgrade (for stability purposes, no reboot, ...).  Why not use `dist-upgrade` or -full-upgrade` if you are unhappy with upgrades restrictions.  From `man apt-get` states "*dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, intelligently handles changing dependencies...*"

Comment: The result of using "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" is shown on the post. It aborts all the time for the upgrade commands. I have included -y to force to proceed. I get some errors. What else could you advise?